# Remote Win-7-Pro PC needs to have 3 enduser logged into it at once

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I have a financial system at work that currently is used by 3 employees and there are 5 physical monitors connected to it. Each monitor has some type of different financial data on it.

What my end users would like to do is get rid of the 5 monitors and then just remote into the financial PC from each of their computers all on the same network.  Remoting into the PC isn't the issue, the issue is getting the financial PC to think that there are physical monitors still plugged into it.

I can get all 3 end users logged in remotely, but they all see the same thing.  So how do I get them logged in as if there where physical monitors so they can see only the info they want to?

Comment: Install Windows 2003/2008 or 2012 server and use terminal services

Comment: "I can get all 3 end users logged in remotely, but they all see the same thing" Oh yeah? Exactly how did you do that?   And are they seeing EXACTLY the same thing in all windows, etc.?  I ask because RDP (remote-desktop) wouldn't allow multiple simultaneous users in Win7 (without hacking) and even then, they'd each get their own session and not see what the others are doing, so as-is there's not enough information here to properly follow what you're telling us and formulate an accurate answer.

Comment: I will go out on a limb and suggest that the number of monitors attached has nothing to do with what users see when they log in, whether it be locally or remotely.

Comment: The end users will use Teamviewer to remote into the Financial-PC once I figure out how to get them to see different windows.  The Financial PC sits between them all right now along with the 5 monitors, with each user only needing to view 1 or 2 of the monitors at a time.  What I am trying to avoid is a computer in the closet/corner of the room with 5 monitors connected because all the users wanting to use TeamViewer to get access to the PC screens.  When I disconnect the monitors everything is now in one window instead of the 5 different ones.

Answer (score 0):

By using a server version of the operating system.

Desktop versions of Windows are limited to one concurrent RDP session for licensing reasons - multiple concurrent connections is one of the features that Microsoft charges extra for.

There are third party utilities you can can use, (and/or dll replacements) but they're not supported by Microsoft, and constitute a licensing violation, so I'm not going to link them here.